# Не могу сделать запрос к mysql, который посчитает количество записей

Tags: mysql, запрос

Со связыванием таблиц не могу никак разобраться, сложно все для меня пока что. В общем делаю форум. Нужно банально вытащить из базы количество ответов в каждой теме. У меня выводится в каждой теме по 1 ответу. Но ведь в одной нет ответов. А все равно показывает единицу. Подскажите, что не так?
Вот таблица с ответами
[image: answers]

Вот таблица с темами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
$query = "SELECT * FROM themes LEFT JOIN users ON themes.add_name = users.id LEFT JOIN section ON themes.section_id = section.id_section WHERE themes.section_id = '$_GET[item]'";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error($link));
  for ($data = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $data[] = $row);
  $content = '';
  foreach ($data as $elem) {
   $id_theme = $elem['id_theme'];
   $query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM answers LEFT JOIN themes ON answers.id_themes =    themes.id_theme WHERE answers.id_themes = themes.id_theme GROUP BY id_themes";
   $result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query1) or die (mysqli_error($link));
   for ($data1 = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1); $data1[] = $row);
    foreach ($data1 as $elem1) {
     $count = $elem1['count'];
    }
   var_dump($data1);

   $content .= "<li class=\"rows_item\">";
    $content .= "<div class=\"rows_main_item_wrap\">";
    $content .=  "<div class=\"rows_main_item_left\">
         <a href=\"?theme=$id_theme\">$elem[head]</a>
         <p>$elem[name]</p>
          </div>";
    $content .=     "<div class=\"rows_main_item_top\">
          <p><span>Ответов: $count</span></p>
        </div>";
    $content .=  "<div class=\"rows_main_item_right\">
          <p> <a class=\"message\" href=\"\"> $elem[message]</a> </p>
          <p> от $elem[name] </p>
        </div>";
    $content .= "</div>";

   $content .= "</li>";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ВЫ формируете вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
FROM answers 
LEFT JOIN themes ON answers.id_themes = themes.id_theme 
WHERE answers.id_themes = themes.id_theme 
GROUP BY id_themes
```

Однако этот запрос считает количество тем для каждого ответа. Весьма странная хотелка. Надо-то наоборот... кроме того, условие во WHERE (полностью дублирующее условие связывания) превращает LEFT JOIN в INNER, что вряд ли нужно.

Правильный запрос должен быть таким:

```
SELECT themes.id_theme, COUNT(answers.id_themes) as count 
FROM themes 
LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.id_themes = themes.id_theme 
GROUP BY themes.id_theme
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я только учусь. Голова уже кругом от этих JOIN связываний.